# How to execute a stored proc which doesnt have any parameters using c# adodb.connection?

Tags: c#

I am trying to execute a stored proc in C# using adodb connection.and SP doesnt have any parameters.

```
           ADODB.Recordset oRecset1 = new ADODB.Recordset();
            oConnection.CursorLocation = ADODB.CursorLocationEnum.adUseClient;
            object objRecAff;
            object parameters1;
           parameters1 = null;
            ADODB.Command cmd = new ADODB.Command();
            cmd.CommandType = ADODB.CommandTypeEnum.adCmdStoredProc;
            cmd.ActiveConnection = oConnection;
            cmd.CommandTimeout = 600;
            cmd.CommandText = "dbo.ImportModel";
            oRecset1 = (ADODB.Recordset)cmd.Execute(out objRecAff,ref parameters1,  (int)ADODB.CommandTypeEnum.adCmdStoredProc);
```

with the above code, i end up in the error message:

"Parameter object is improperly defined. Inconsistent or incomplete information was provided." any idea how to execute sp without parameters?

Comment: object recordsAffected = new object();
            ADODB.Recordset rs =  cmd.Execute(out recordsAffected);

Comment: Since I know people are going to ask (or even *answer*): have you established that there is no ADO.NET provider for the system you're accessing? Using ADO from C# isn't what you'd call the mainstream solution (and will lead to headscratchers like this, where you're not sure how to tickle its argument requirements just right).

Comment: Hi. thank you for replying. its a legacy code which got converted to c# and they are using adodb itself, there is n ADO.NET.

Comment: @jdweng- I tried this code. but didnt work... object recordsAffected = new object(); ADODB.Recordset rs = cmd.Execute(out recordsAffected);

Comment: Try calling cmd.Execute with only the first parameter (e.g. don't specify parameters 2 and 3).